# Probability of A taking exactly one more try than B?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have an end of exercise question, that I am not able to solve.
Question goes like, Suppose A passes a test with probability 0.6, and B passes the same test with probability 0.8. If both students keep on taking the test until it is passed, what is the probability that A will need exactly one more attempt to pass the test than B. That is if B passes the test in K takes, A is going to pass the test in K+1 takes.

Only possible way I can think of solving this problem is to find the expected number of attempts B require, with E[X] = 1/p, that comes out to be 1.25 (rounded off to 2) , and then find the probability of A passing the same test in 2+1 = 3 attempts. This probability turns out to be (0.4^2)*(0.6) = 0.48.

Is this approach right, I believe there needs to be some more generic way to solve this problem, and produce a more generic equation, in form of k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the probability that $A$ passes and $q$ be the probability that $B$ passes.

Assuming independence, the probability that $A$ requires $n+1$ tries and $B$ requires $n$ tries is $(1-p)^np(1-q)^{n-1}q$ ($A$ fails $n$ times and then passes while $q$ fails $n-1$ times and then passes).

Therefore, the probability that it $A$ passes in $n+1$ tries and $B$ passes in $n$ tries is $pq(1-p)[(1-p)(1-q)]^{n-1}$.  Summing this for all choices of $n$ gives the total probability (it's a geometric series).